# How to place the legend beside the figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot something with the legend outside the figure. I am using

```
 legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1))
```

To position the legend and then I have to do

```
 tight_layout()
```

To make sure the plot is complete when saved to a file.

Unfortunately, `tight_layout` pushes the legend into the figure no matter what values I put in the legend function. Is there any other way to make sure the legend is not touching the figure?

Comment: A lot about legend outside axes is found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317). I do not understand the problem here, but maybe it would become clearer when using the notions "figure" and "axes" [correctly](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#parts-of-a-figure)?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but you could try`plt.savefig('filename.png', bbox_inches='tight')` without calling `tight_layout` when you save the figure. You can also use the `pad_inches` parameter if the legend is cut off.